# Google Play Console Developers Account - Can change it from organization to personal

Tags: google-play-console, google-developers-console

I registered the wrong organization account. Now they ask me to verify my identity with organization information. Can change it from organization to personal?
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. on left side menu there a section called account details and there you will find you account type and you can choose to modify it.